Is type narrowing necessary after restricting with conditional type?
In the following contrived snippet, I am using conditional types to restrict the input values to the doSomething function. This works correctly. I'm confused as to why I'm not getting the same benefit from within the function directly. I could do additional type narrowing inside the function, but this feels like double work.
Is type narrowing necessary after restricting with conditional type?
Is there another approach I could use to write less type narrowing? Maybe with function overloading? (I don't know anything about this, just that it exists)
type TObj = { x: number, y: number }
type TTup = [number, number]

function doSomething<TOption extends boolean, TData extends TOption extends true ? TTup : TObj>(data: TData, someOption: TOption){
    if (someOption && !Array.isArray(data)){
        throw 'this should be impossible'
    }

    if (someOption){
        console.log(data) //data is TObj | TTup, should be TTup
        //          ^?
    }
    else {
        console.log(data) //data is TObj | TTup, should be TObj
        //          ^?
    }
}

doSomething({ x: 1, y: 1 }, false) //valid, correct
doSomething([1,1], true) //valid, correct

doSomething({ x: 1, y: 1 }, true) //invalid, correct
doSomething([1,1], false) //invalid, correct

TS playground link

No, without ms/TS#33014 or ms/TS#33912 you cant mix generics with control flow analysis, especially not with generic types. Given your example I'd refactor to destructured tuple rest param as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a or find a duplicate; if not, what's mising?

Your response totally answers my question. Those links are very informative and your proposed workaround is very clever. Please write it up and I'll approve it asap. Thank you very much.
